# Error in paste() <- function target of assignment expands to non-language object

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a data frame and would like to create sub data frames from each of those columns (except for the first one).
But when trying to do this with a for loop, I get an error.

Here's a toy data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(my_names=sample(LETTERS,4,replace=F),
+                  column2=sample(1.3:100.3,4,replace=T),
+                  column3=sample(1.3:100.3,4,replace=T),
+                  column4=sample(1.3:100.3,4,replace=T),
+                  column5=sample(1.3:100.3,4,replace=T))
> df
  my_names column2 column3 column4 column5
1        K     7.3    18.3    11.3    27.3
2        N    17.3    56.3    92.3    82.3
3        R    66.3     8.3    62.3    58.3
4        Y    43.3    22.3    72.3    23.3
>
```

What I want to get, for one of the columns, can be done like this:

```
> top <- 2
> top_column2 <- df %>% arrange(desc(column2)) %>% select(my_names, column2) %>% top_n(top, column2) %>% mutate(column2=round(column2))
> top_column2
  my_names column2
1        R      66
2        Y      43
>
```

Now the code I tried to use:

```
> for(i in 2:ncol(df)) {
+   paste("top", colnames(df)[i], sep="_") <- 
+     df %>% arrange(desc(i)) %>% select(my_names, i) %>% top_n(top, i) %>% mutate(i=round(i))
+   }
Error in paste("top", colnames(df)[i], sep = "_") <- df %>% arrange(desc(i)) %>%  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

After googling, I tried also assign(paste(), function):

```
> for(i in 2:ncol(df)) {
+   assign(paste("top", colnames(df)[i], sep="_"), 
+     df %>% arrange(desc(i)) %>% select(my_names, i) %>% top_n(top, i) %>% mutate(i=round(i))) 
+ }
> top_column4
  my_names column4 i
1        K    11.3 4
2        N    92.3 4
3        R    62.3 4
4        Y    72.3 4
```

Four data frames were created with the right name but none of the functions were applied to the columns.

Can anybody suggest how to deal with this?

Comment: As usual (this is asked way too frequently), the solution is using a list. Do `mylist <- list()` before the loop and then you can do `mylist[[paste("top", colnames(df)[i], sep="_")]] <- ...`. After the loop you will have all four data.frames in one list. That is a good thing and they should stay together in that list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried what you suggested but I get the same as with assign(), the data frames are created (now inside the list) but the functions are not applied: ‘‘‘test_list <- list()‘‘‘ then ‘‘‘for(i in 2:ncol(df)) {
  test_list[[paste("top", colnames(df)[i], sep="_")]] <- 
               df %>% arrange(desc(i)) %>% select(my_names, i) %>% top_n(top, i) %>% mutate(i=round(i))
}‘‘‘

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that. I don't use dplyr. However, I assume the issue is with non-standard evaluation (it looks for a column `i` not for a column with the name stored in `i`). You can probably add some random `!` somewhere to "fix" that.